# Maximum number of linearly independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us consider the following vectors with $n$ components:
$$(a-1,-1,-1,\dots,-1)$$
$$(-1,a-1,-1,\dots,-1)$$
$$\dots$$
$$(-1,-1,-1,\dots,a-1)\, .$$
We have $n$ vectors and $a\in N$, $a>1$. I think that the maximum number of linearly independent vectors is $n-1$. I don't understand why (and wheter) this is true.

Would appreciate any tips to prove this is the case.

Comment: is there a typo for the last component? I mean the position of $a-1$.

Comment: @SiongthyeGoh, thank you!

Comment: Got nothing from the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant is $a^n - n a^{n-1}$. One way to see this (for $a\neq 0$):
$$ \det(aI-ee^T) = a^n \det(I-\frac{1}{a} e e^T) = a^n (1-\frac{1}{a} {\rm tr} (e e^T))= a^n (1 -\frac{1}{a} n) = a^n - n a^{n-1}$$
We used here that when $M=x y^T$ has rank one then
$\det(I-M)=1-{\rm tr} M = 1 -y^T x$. This follows by looking at the matrix in a basis consisting of $x, v_2,...,v_n$ with $x$ being the vector coming from $M$ and $v_2,...,v_n$ be a complement (arbitrary). The matrix in this basis
takes the form:
 $$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1-y^T x & y^T v_2 & y^T v_3 & ... & v_n \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0\\
   . & . & . & ... & .\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 1 
\end{matrix} \right) $$
from which one obtains the determinant.

When $a=0$ the rank is 1.

When $a=n$ the rank is $n-1$. 
To see this consider the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix obtained by omitting the n'th column and row. That matrix is of the same form but the determinant is $a^{n-1} - (n-1) a^{n-2}=n^{n-2}\neq 0$

Otherwise, the rank is $n$.

Comment: Thank you! What is $ee^T$? And why $ a^n \det(I-\frac{1}{a} e e^T) = a^n (1-\frac{1}{a} {\rm tr} (e e^T))$?

Comment: $e^T=(1,...,1)$ and whenever $M=xy^T$ has rank one, then $\det(I-M) = 1-{\rm tr} M=1-y^T x$ which you may show e.g. by looking at the matrix in a suitable basis (which includes an element of ${\rm im} M$).

Comment: Excuse me but it is still unclear. I don't understand why $\det(I-M) = 1-{\rm tr} M$.

Comment: And why , when $a=n$ the rank is $n-1$?

Answer (score 1):

$(3,-1)$ and $(-1,3)$ are linearly independent.

Hence the number of linearly independent vectors can be $n$.